# Webform submit with specific page url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webforms, business-catalyst

I have a website, it has many portfolio pages. And each page has "Contact Us" form. But I have used one web form module for every portfolio, so I was having problem to find out `from which page customer has submitted the form`.

I have seen few websites doing submit the form with `specific page URL on the Email`, then website owner can identify the page.

How can I do something like this?

I was thinking to add select option in web form. But since we are having many pages, it makes hard to website visitors.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**FYI** : CMS is Business Catalyst.

Just Let me know your suggests.

Here my Current web form module. im free to edit delete modify web form in BC.

```
<form action="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com.au/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=42328&amp;OID={module_oid}&amp;OTYPE={module_otype}&amp;EID={module_eid}&amp;CID={module_cid}" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm83244(this)" method="post" name="catwebformform83244">
    <p>Your Name (required)<br />
    <span class=""><input type="text" aria-required="true" class="" size="40" name="FullName" /></span> </p>
    <p>Your Email (required)<br />
    <input type="email" aria-required="true" class="" size="40" name="EmailAddress" /></p>
    <p>Your Phone Number<br />
    <span class=""><input type="tel" class="" size="40" name="WorkPhone" /></span></p>
    <p>On Which Date?<br />
    <span class=""><input type="text" size="40" onfocus="displayDatePicker('CAT_Custom_26272');return false;" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" readonly="readonly" class="" id="CAT_Custom_26272" name="CAT_Custom_26272" /> </span></p>
    <p>Your Message<br />
    <textarea class="" rows="10" cols="40" name="CAT_Custom_26273"></textarea> </p>
    <p><input type="submit" id="catwebformbutton" class="button" value="Send" /></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxx.australianwebsitedevelopment.com.au/CatalystScripts/ValidationFunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxx.australianwebsitedevelopment.com.au/CatalystScripts/Java_DatePicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var submitcount83244 = 0;function checkWholeForm83244(theForm){var why = "";if (theForm.FirstName) why += isEmpty(theForm.FirstName.value, "First Name"); if (theForm.LastName) why += isEmpty(theForm.LastName.value, "Last Name"); if (theForm.EmailAddress) why += checkEmail(theForm.EmailAddress.value); if (theForm.WorkPhone) why += isEmpty(theForm.WorkPhone.value, "Work Phone Number"); if (theForm.CAT_Custom_26272) if (theForm.CAT_Custom_26272.value.length > 0) why += checkDate(theForm.CAT_Custom_26272.value,"On Which Date?");if(why != ""){alert(why);return false;}if(submitcount83244 == 0){submitcount83244++;theForm.submit();return false;}else{alert("Form submission is in progress.");return false;}}
//]]>
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your current code for the form ? What language would you use to achieve that (PHP, JS, ?)?

Comment: @enguerranws since we are using Business Catalyst we dont have access to the inner source code to do the changes. and they are using ASP.net i would like to do something with javascript. i can add website URL here. but it has some 18+ content. :)

Comment: Can you add an element to the form ?

Comment: @enguerranws yes, i can add what ever elements to the form. like wordpress it has web form builder i can add any thing for it and make webform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, you can do something like that :

HTML :

```
<input type="hidden" id="sourcePage" name="sourcePage" />
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // if you didn't set it before
  var docHref = document.URL;     
  $('#sourcePage').attr('value', docHref);  
});
```

This will add the current URL to the value of an input, so you'll be able to send this data to your form.